# Accessing parent controller data in combination with isolated scope in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

First the code, then the explanation:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-directive data="1" />
    <my-directive data="2" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module("myApp", []).directive("myDirective", function ($parent) {
  return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
          data: "@",
      },
      template: function(element, attrs){
        switch(attrs.data){
          case '1':
            return '<h3>'+ $parent.stringForDirective1 + '</h3>';
          case '2':
            return '<h3>'+ $parent.stringForDirective2 + '</h3>';
        }
      }
  };
}).controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.stringForDirective1 = 'I was returned by the directive with HTML attribute data having the value 1.'
$scope.stringForDirective2 = 'I was returned by the directive with HTML attribute data having the value 2.'
});
```

Now for the explanation. If I were to set 'scope: false' on my directive, I could easily access the controller's data as the directive is positioned inside of its scope. However, from my understanding, in order to use any value from an HTML attribute with a custom directive, the entire directive must be put into an isolated scope.

**I want to use an HTML attribute to return a template that uses the parent controller's data.**

How do I get the benefits of the controller data when using 'scope: false' while being able to pass in a custom HTML attribute?

*The $parent example does not work, I simply added it to show the way I've been thinking towards a solution, and I think it shows my intent clearly.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you injected the `$parent` dependency. I hope that was the one you only used to show how you were thinking: `The $parent example does not work, I simply added it to show the way I've been thinking towards a solution, and I think it shows my intent clearly.`

---

Anyway, you don't need any of that. To make it all work, simply get rid of that dependency, don't concat the parent scope values into the template, but let Angular take care of it after it compiles the template (using the double curly braces for binding):

```
switch(attrs.data){
      case '1':
        return '<h3>{{$parent.stringForDirective1}}</h3>';
      case '2':
        return '<h3>{{$parent.stringForDirective2}}</h3>';
    }
```

That will still look for `scope.$parent`, which is what you wanted.

**See the fully working example here**: http://plnkr.co/edit/pW5G2Yy4SelW5DxKBMqW?p=preview

**Or here, as a snippet**:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        data: "@",
      },
      template: function(element, attrs) {
        switch (attrs.data) {
          case '1':
            return '<h3>{{$parent.stringForDirective1}}</h3>';
          case '2':
            return '<h3>{{$parent.stringForDirective2}}</h3>';
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.stringForDirective1 = 'I was returned by the directive with HTML attribute data having the value 1.'
    $scope.stringForDirective2 = 'I was returned by the directive with HTML attribute data having the value 2.'
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-directive data="1"></my-directive>
    <my-directive data="2"></my-directive>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Note: had to specify the directive closing tag, since the shorthand version reads only the first directive (Plunker saying that the trailing solidus is not allowed on your directive element), see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qt0z0poU0ogoQq4C9a3n?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about directives having access to $parent by default in their template. I assume this is because the directive template returns the string before Angular evaluates?

Comment: `$parent` is a part of every scope object (just like `$root`, etc...). So, for example, if you put `{{something}}` in your template, it will look for `scope.something`, right? The same thing happens when you put `{{$parent}}` - it will look for `scope.$parent`. It's mentioned here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope Bear in mind that your directive won't be much reusable because of the whole approach of it depending on the controller scope (though I'm sure you're aware of that).

Answer (score -1):

There are three possible modes of scope that a directive can have:

1. isolated scope (scope: {})
2. child scope (scope: true)
3. inherited scope (scope: false)

Depending on the needs of your directive, any one of these scope modes is valid.

If you want to create a directive with isolated scope, then you can pass in the models to your directive's isolated scope through the element's attributes:

```
scope: {
    modelA: '=', // model binding
    modelB: '@', // string binding
    modelC: '&'  // method binding in parent scope
}
```

Attributes

```
<div directive model-a="user" model-b="hello {{ user.name }}" model-c="addUser(user)"></div>
```

Example (not an ideal directive implementation but done to show how models can be passed to an isolated scope through attributes)

```
angular.module("myApp", []).directive("myDirective", function ($parent) {
  return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
          data: "@",
          stringForDirective1: '=?',
          stringForDirective2: '=?'
      },
      template: '<h3 ng-if="data = '1'">{{stringForDirective1 }}</h3><h3 ng-if="data = '2'">{{stringForDirective2 }}</h3>'

  };
}).controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.stringForDirective1 = 'I was returned by the directive with HTML attribute data having the value 1.'
$scope.stringForDirective2 = 'I was returned by the directive with HTML attribute data having the value 2.'
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-directive data="1" string-for-directive1="stringForDirective1" />
    <my-directive data="2" string-for-directive2="stringForDirective2" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @pixebits How do I pass in a custom HTML attribute while retaining the benefits of inherited scope?

Comment: You can reap the benefits of inherited scope (scope: false, in your directive). Then you don't need to pass anything through attributes.

Comment: But the problem is that I want to, in addition to having access to the parent scope. I want to pass in an attribute that is used as conditional logic to return a string derived from the parent scope (see my example).